# Need help with my MySQL PROCEDURE #1193 - Unknown system variable

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I've this simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testing`
(
    `testing_ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `meter` INT NOT NULL,
    `price` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL,
    `price_per_meter` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`testing_ID`)
)
```

And I've written this MySQL `PROCEDURE`:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `price_per_meter_calc` (price DECIMAL(12,2))
BEGIN
    SET price_per_meter = price/meter;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

but I've got an error `#1193 - Unknown system variable 'price_per_meter'`. I believe it's pretty straightforward code. What I want is simply MySQL to automatically calculate `price_per_meter` given the user will only insert `price` and `meter` values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare variable first and then only you can set the value.

Something like:

```
DECLARE price_per_meter DECIMAL(6,2);
```

Then other part is just logics.

Answer (score 0):

The Procedure fails to mention the table containing `price_per_meter` and `meter`.

Do you really want to feed in `price`?  Do you want to store `price` in the table -- if so, need another set.  Or do you want to use the `price` that is already in the table -- if so, don't pass it in.

My recommendation is to completely erase the `STORED PROCEDURE` and start over.  Think about what you "have" and what you "want to achieve", and what it takes to get from one to the other.